# WIX: XmlFile/XmlConfig unable to find node in XSLT file (issue with namespace?)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, wix

I'm trying to change an xslt file during installation.

The xslt file looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:outcome="http://www.test.co.uk/schemas" xmlns:func="http://www.test.co.uk/core/functions">

    <xsl:import href="someFile.xslt" />
    <xsl:import href="someFile2.xslt" />

    <xsl:template name="someName" match="/outcome:client">
        ...
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have to change href attribute of import nodes during installation.

I've tried to use XmlFile and XmlConfig with following element paths:

```
//*[\[]namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' and local-name()='import' and contains(@href, 'someFile.xslt')[\]]

//xsl:stylesheet/xsl:import[\[]@href='someFile.xslt'[\]]

//xsl:import[\[]@href='someFile.xslt'[\]]
```

But without success, during installtion there is an error stating that it couldn't find node. (In online xpath testers it's working as it should)

Comment: Please add a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what more can I add. I've shown an xslt that I need to change, I've shown xpath queries I've tried that are working in 'pure' xpath but not in WIX Installer.